# Getting error curl: (3) Port number ended with ' ' while executing curl POST from bash script

Tags: bash, curl, sh

I am trying to execute curl from bash script and while running POST curl command it returns curl: (3) Port number ended with ' ' error .

for e.g. script.sh contains following curl

```sh
curl -k -X -H "content-type: application/json" POST -d 
  '{\"test_field\": \"test.com\",
     \"head\": \"-----BEGIN REQUEST-----\n
MIICvzCCAacCAQAwejgVPmU0J/BUbIuyOC5KXMYkc2KqggRBLpLdKs8ODo5cVKzVa7UOmNGRdGncM1WC0HHnn8E47fYnjmn72WQ94L1kBqJuM+olYbOtyop84lmYo0LTm0DH/w4DBlzUdp4 Z8EYFuRtv1En2TkJ6YxI86z7Bwc/I20HPZPQYEQ4v=\n
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----\"
  }' https://mytestserver/v1/testfield
```

It results in:

```sh
curl: (3) Port number ended with ' '
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: POST
{"errors":[]}
```

If I execute the same from postman with same body content it executes successfully.

The content

```sh
-----BEGIN REQUEST-----
MIICvzCCAacCAQAwejgVPmU0J/BUbIuyOC5KXMYkc2KqggRBLpLdKs8ODo5cVKzVa7UOmNGRdGncM1WC0HHnn8E47fYnjmn72WQ94L1kBqJuM+olYbOtyop84lmYo0LTm0DH/w4DBlzUdp4 Z8EYFuRtv1En2TkJ6YxI86z7Bwc/I20HPZPQYEQ4v=
-----END REQUEST-----
```

has space and / special character. I tried to escape it but wasn't successful.

Comment: not sure about your `curl` context, but in a regular shell script context, `'single-quoted data "dbl-quoted data" should be sufficient'`  (no need to escape the dbl-quotes). Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

The error message indicate that the 'POST' argument is mistaken to be host name. Most likely, because Curl expect the '-X' to be followed with the (http) command.

As per 'curl' man page: *Normally you don't need this option. All sorts of GET, HEAD, POST and PUT requests are rather invoked by using dedicated command line options*.

Consider one of the alternatives:

```
curl -k -X POST -H 'content-type: ...' -d '{ ...}' https://mytestserver/...
```

OR, letting curl do it's magic: **RECOMMENDED**

```
curl -k -H 'content-type: ...' -d '{ ...}' https://mytestserver/...
```